# Postmates API to send Ordering detail

Tags: webhooks, postmates

From what I've learnt [here](https://postmates.com/developer/docs), Postmates API is about other system to schedule delivery using Postmates Service.

We are as POS solution provider is looking for a different integration in which Orders from Postmates will come to our POS system.

Webhooks would be the best solution, but so far the Webhooks of Postmates is not sending the Order detail.

Is there any possible way for POS applications to get Order detail from Postmates?

Comment: Have you tried doing a [Get a Delivery](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/endpoints#get_delivery) using the `delivery_id` from the webhook request?

Comment: That endpoint return Delivery related information and not including what's are actual delivered (for example: 2 x pizza with xxx toppings).

Comment: I don't use the Postmates service or API, but looks to me like you specify that level of detail when the delivery is created using `manifest_items`. If those are set, then it looks to me like you get that detail back with GET.

Comment: That looks like it in the simplest form but should be sufficient! Can you please turn your comment into answer so I can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Have you got any progress on this? I can only list the deliveries (via GET request) that were requested by me. However, I'm interested in getting the deliveries which customers placed through Postmates website or Postmates app.